# Public Key Certificate Pinning alternatives

Tags: man-in-the-middle, certificate-pinning

In the domain of mobile application, certificate pinning topic is still relevant. I am trying to get opinions on best alternatives, because certificate pinning needs the storage of public keys within the mobile app, which is taken to be an operational overhead to have a app release only for the supporting an update of certificate on the server.

Is there a way to avoid storing the key on the mobile app (client side) and still be able to achieve certificate pinning? Or are there any better alternatives.